# ProGuard - Игнорирование библиотеки JNA

Tags: java, proguard

Всем привет, есть проблема, у меня в проекте есть JNA, но как я понял, обфусцировать её нельзя, иначе будет крашить, так вот, я использую ProGuard GUI. И мне надо сделать так, что бы ProGuard игнорировал JNA, вообще с ней ничего не делал. Вот мои настройки:

[image: Config]

Может я не так делаю, но по моему что бы он ее игнорировал надо добавить в 'Keep package name', но гуард всё равно её обфусцирует, можно ли сделать что бы гуард её игнорировал?